# Property setter not accessed when the property changed by external class

Tags: c#, properties

I have a public class that is is used to create a dll. It has a variable and a property. Let`s assume it looks like this:

```
public class Main
{
    private int _someInt = 0;
    public int SomeInt
    {
        get { return this._someInt; }
        set
        {
            this._someInt = value;
            if (this._someInt == 1)
            {
                _someInt = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public int ExecuteMain()
    {
        OtherClass.DoSomething(this.SomeInt);
    }
}
```

I also have another class, in a separate project in the `OtherClass` class, that has the static `DoSomething` method:

```
public static void DoSomething(int someInt)
{
    someInt = 1;
}
```

My problem is that `SomeInt` property in the `Main` class is getting set to 1 by the `DoSomething` method of `OtherClass`, but this does not trigger the setter in the `Main` class' property. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you are just setting the value of a parameter, it has no correlation to the value you passed in other than its value, you could either pass by `ref` or find a way of accessing the variable

Comment: I tried with the "out" keyword, but I can't use a property in this case. And i need to capture the event when SomeInt changes to 1. Any other way this can be done?

Comment: Having given it a thought... I wrap the int in an object. If I am not mistaken, objects are passed by reference, so I should get the value changed. And the value changes indeed, but i still can`t trigger the setter.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is passing SomeInt **by value** to the DoSomething method, which gets a **copy** of the int and just changes its local value.

You can:

1. Pass by ref: public static void DoSomething(ref int someInt)
2. Pass the Main class and change the value inside DoSomething:

   public static void DoSomething(Mainclass main)
   {main.SomeInt = 1}

Comment: 1. no, i can`t. I can`t pass a property with ref or out.
2. this is the thing, i don`t want to create an instance of the Main class in the OtherClass, because the Main class already references the OtherClass and uses it`s methods. I don`t want to end up with some kind of circular references, might get problematic when the code grows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this,even if you pass the field by *reference* using `ref` keyword it's not gonna work because your property has a *setter* method not your field.You should be changing the value of your property, in order to execute the *setter* method and perform the validation.

You can do that,passing the current instance of your class instead of the field, for example:

```
public int ExecuteMain()
{
    OtherClass.DoSomething(this); // just pass current instance using 'this'
}

public static void DoSomething(Main obj)
{
    obj.SomeInt = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it invoke the setter logic, one option is to do something like this:

```
public static void DoSomething(Action<int> setSomeInt)
{
    setSomeInt(1);
}
```

then call it like this:

```
public int ExecuteMain()
{
    OtherClass.DoSomething(x => this.SomeInt = x);
}
```

The concept here is that what you're really giving the method is not a variable that can be set, but rather an action that can be performed.  This is an important distinction, as setting a property is really a kind of action, which can have an arbitrarily complex implementation.  This approach is a bit awkward in practice, though, so you'll want to think carefully about what you're really trying to do here and whether there's a better way to express the desired dependency.